# Vuetify combobox add option multiple times?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the vuetify framework and I am running into this issue where I am not sure how I can add an item from the list multiple times. I have a dropdown list and I would like to add the option `foo` or any option multiple times on select. Here is a link to the demo [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/PoqwZJE).

So right now if I select foo or any other option and then select it again from the dropdown list, it goes away, instead I want another chip with same option
added into it?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          text: 'Foo',
          value: 'foo'
        },
        {
          text: 'Bar',
          value: 'bar'
        },
        {
          text: 'biz',
          value: 'buzz'
        },
        {
          text: 'buzz',
          value: 'buzz'
        }
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-combobox :items="items" label="Add Multiple Chips" multiple small-chips solo deletable-chips>
        <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }">
      <v-list-tile-content>
        {{item.text}}
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </template>
        <template v-slot:selection="{ index, item }">
      <v-chip close dark color="info">
        {{ item.text }}
      </v-chip> 
    </template>
      </v-combobox>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

If anyone has any clue on how to achieve this. It will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you planning to allow as many identical items as possible or would there be a limitation like you'll allow at most 4 *foo*s, 2 *bar*s  etc.? I am asking it to determine how the array `items` could be enriched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of small adjustments,

- put a `.stop` on the item click to prevent Vuetify from processing after your handler
- tell the combo-box to use arr for `:value`
- add a delete click handler to `v-chip` and corresponding method (NB this works on Vuetify 2.1.0, but not on Vuetify 1.5.14 as used on the Codepen. If you don't need that specific version, install the latest.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/abOObjQ?editors=1011) Vuetify v1.5.14

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dawn-clogt) Vuetify v2.1.0

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-container>
        <v-combobox
          :items="items"
          label="Add Multiple Chips"
          multiple
          small-chips
          solo
          deletable-chips
          :value="arr"
        >
          <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }">
            <v-list-tile-content @click.stop="multipleSelection(item)">{{item.text}}</v-list-tile-content>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:selection="{ index, item }">
            <v-chip close dark color="info" 
               @click:close="deleteChip(item)" >{{ item.text }}</v-chip>
          </template>
        </v-combobox>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "playground",
  data: () => ({
    arr: [],
    items: [
      {
        text: "Foo",
        value: "foo"
      },
      {
        text: "Bar",
        value: "bar"
      },
      {
        text: "biz",
        value: "buzz"
      },
      {
        text: "buzz",
        value: "buzz"
      }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    multipleSelection(item) {
      this.arr.push({...item});
      console.log(this.arr);
    },
    deleteChip(item) {
      this.arr = this.arr.filter(x => x !== item);
      console.log(this.arr);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent. I'll figure out the delete for v 1.5. Thank you :D

Comment: I think there seems to be some issue with the combobox, when i type in something and then click enter to add the text, that doesn't seem to work. So from the dropdowns i am able to select,but it doesn't generate text in chips when typed by the user.

Comment: I never thought about typing in the combobox - is that normal? Usually a combo restricts to things in the list. If I'm following the steps correctly, the same happens on the original Codepen, so it's not my mods.

Comment: Will take a look, may be fixable in multipleSelection method.

Comment: Also suggest you un-accept and add a note to the question, some else might know this.

Comment: Also, there's another issue, try adding enough so the options wrap in the next row. you'll see the dropdown should adjust itself but that doesn't happening either and then delete the chips and the  dropdown menu stays detached.

Comment: Actually nevermind the ability to add tags, rather prevent adding new tags when clicked enter. So you should only be able to select from the dropdown, can't add new.but still filter. okay this is becoming a mess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207546/discussion-between-somethingwhatever-and-richard-matsen).

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the problem of long selection lists being obscured by the dropdown menu,

The dropdown menu looks like this at runtime (via chrome developer tools)

```html
<div class="v-menu__content theme--light menuable__content__active v-autocomplete__content"
  style="max-height: 304px; min-width: 357px; top: 149px; left: 12px; transform-origin: left top; z-index: 8;">
  <div role="listbox" tabindex="-1" class="v-list v-select-list v-sheet v-sheet--tile theme--light theme--light"
    id="list-261">
    <div tabindex="0" role="menuitem" id="list-item-267" class="v-list-item v-list-item--link theme--light">Foo</div>
    <div tabindex="0" role="menuitem" id="list-item-268" class="v-list-item v-list-item--link theme--light">Bar</div>
    <div tabindex="0" role="menuitem" id="list-item-269" class="v-list-item v-list-item--link theme--light">biz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and has these styles

```js
element.style {
  max-height: 304px;
  min-width: 357px;
  top: 149px;
  left: 12px;
  transform-origin: left top;
  z-index: 8;
}
```

Vuetify changes the `top: 149px` in it's selection handler, but since we turned that off we need to call `updateMenuDimensions()` in our own handler `multipleSelection()`.

To do this, add a ref to the combobox,

```html
<v-combobox
  :items="items"
  label="Add Multiple Chips"
  multiple
  small-chips
  solo
  deletable-chips
  :value="arr"
  ref="combobox"
>
  ...
</v-combobox>
```

Then add the call to updateMenuDimensions, inside a `nextTick()` to allow the selection box to settle.

```js
methods: {
  multipleSelection(item) {
    this.arr.push({ ...item });
    console.log(this.arr);
    this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.combobox.updateMenuDimensions())
  },
  deleteChip(item) {
    this.arr = this.arr.filter(x => x !== item);
    console.log(this.arr);
    this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.combobox.updateMenuDimensions())
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/GRJJMaz?editors=1011) Vuetify v1.5.14 (NB not deleting chips).

Answer (score 0):

**Preventing text from adding an item**

There's another problem (for anyone following here but not seeing the chat room discussion). I've separated the answers for each issue, to make things easier to follow.

Feel free to vote on all answers :).

**Problem**

If the user types into the combobox, the expectation is that the list will be filtered, and it is.

But if the user presses enter after the text, an item is added and this is not desired.

We tried a permutations of event suppression, including,

- @keydown.enter.prevent
- @keypress.enter.prevent
- @submit.prevent
- @keydown.enter.prevent="enterItem" with `event.preventDefault()` in the handler
- @blur.prevent

plus permutations with `.stop`, `.capture`.

None of the event suppression worked, so a hacky way to do it is to `v-if` the `v-chip`

```html
<v-combobox
  ...various attributes as before
>

  <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }">
    ...
  </template>

  <template v-slot:selection="{ index, item }">
    <v-chip v-if="item.text" ...other attributes >{{ item.text }}</v-chip>
  </template>

</v-combobox>
```

This works because the added item has no text (reason unknown), and the variable `this.arr` does not get modified when pressing the enter key as described.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/dyooJJG?editors=1011)